# Analytical Solution of Two Simultaneous Partial Differential Equations

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations

I am looking for an analytic solution for the following two equations in the variables $v(x,t)$ and $u(x,t)$:
$$
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x} = -m\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t} \\
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} =-n \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial t} -av^5
\end{cases}
$$
The boundary conditions are 
$$
v(0,t)=E\qquad u(l,t)=0
$$
The constants  $m,n,a,E$ and $l$  are  positive and non-zero.
Thanks in advance.

Note: This is a simplified version of my earlier (unanswered) question posted on February 13, 2019.

Comment: Here is link to the previous question mentioned in the post: [Analytical solution of a system of nonlinear PDEs](https://mathoverflow.net/q/323157).

Answer (score 2):

There's an obvious analytic answer:

$$
v(x,t) = E\qquad u(x,t) = a E^5 (l-x)
$$

Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Thanks very much. Apparently, there are more than one solution. This suggested answer is mathematically sound and  interesting. As a matter of fact, I am looking for a solution(s) that also depend on the two other constants m and n. I think that the proposed answer is a special solution that prevails when  t approaches infinity.